# Permission denied for files in www-data

Tags: permissions, mediawiki

I have image files being uploaded with mediawiki, and they are setting the owner as www-data. Viewing the files results in 403 forbidden. (all other site files owned by SITE_USER).

The SITE_USER and www-data are both in each others (secondary) groups.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:
My Apache directives

```
DocumentRoot "/home/SITE_USER/public_html/en.domain.org"
ServerName en.domain.org
# Alias for Wiki so images work
Alias /images "/home/SITE_USER/public_html/mediawiki/sites/images"    
<Directory "/home/SITE_USER/public_html/en.domain.org">
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}//index.php [L]
## http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache
# Enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# Short url for wiki pages
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
# Redirect / to Main Page
RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
#
Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Can you post permissions of the file which you are trying to access via browser ? and output of command `id SITE_USER`. Thank you

Comment: -rw-r--r--   is the permission of the file itself.   `uid=1000(SITE_USER) gid=1000(SITE_USER) groups=1000(SITE_USER),27(sudo),33(www-data)`. I changed everything to `chown -R SITE_USER:SITE_USER images`, but still 403.

Comment: Have you tried with www-data instead?

Comment: Yes, the entire images dir and below either www-data:www-data or SITE_USER: SITE_USER, both result in 403. Now I am thinking the problem is deeper, maybe apache directory listing permissions... I'm not so expert.

Comment: Ok share us your website apache configuration. Thank you.

Comment: I have added the directives in an edit to my OP. Is there something else needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding

```
<Directory "/home/DOMAIN/public_html/mediawiki/sites/images">
allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```